# AudioException was unhandled / Audio device error in speech recognition program

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech, speech-synthesis

I am developing a speech recognition software using c sharp and i am having this problem i searched it on google but did not find any solution and also posted the question in msdn but no one seems to help and i also reinstalled my audio device driver and it is updated version , i have sony vaio fit 15218sgw and it is realtek audio device and i am using visual studio 2013 the code at line 171,172,173 is

```
case "who is your daddy":
                    Nevan.Speak("I dont have a daddy");
                    break;
```

)

The error :
        System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.AudioException was unhandled by user code
        HResult=-2146233088
        Message=Audio device error encountered. - Error Code: 0x4
        Source=System.Speech
        StackTrace:
        at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.Speak(Prompt prompt)
        at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
        at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(String textToSpeak)
        at Nevan.Form1._recognizer_SpeechRecognized(Object sender,SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Shehroz\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Nevan\Nevan\Form1.cs:line 172
       at System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognizedProxy(Object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
  InnerException:

Comment: Looks like a driver issue or, worse, a hardware problem. Not sure there is anything we can do.

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
     `speechSynthesizer.Speak("I dont have a daddy");`